# inputparameter uploadlocation is invalid in windows phone while calling backgrounduploadasync method with liveconnectclient in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I always get the below error while trying to upload the photo chosen from pictures.

> System.ArgumentException: Input parameter 'uploadLocation' is invalid.
>   'uploadLocation' must be rooted in \shared\transfers. Parameter name:
>   uploadLocation

The path of the image files chosen was:

> C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Camera Roll\WP_20130228_001.jpg.

Any idea how I can supply the image file in the expected format?

```
MainPage.client.BackgroundUploadAsync("ToFolder", new System.Uri("C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Camera Roll\WP_20130228_001.jpg"), OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
```

Comment: You're trying to access an image on your PC, from your phone? I don't think it can work like that. Check out the answer on this question, it explains `BackgroundUploadAsync()` a little better, and links to some documentation.

Comment: Oops, here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482876/wp8-upload-file-to-skydrive

Answer (score 0):

The c drive always come in windows phone also.just by removing the entire path and only giving the file name as parameter has fixed the issue.